# ViewPager with ListView using FragmentStatePageAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

Can any one help me out this requirement . I want to create a list view and in each row there will be a viewpager whose adapter will FragmentStatePageApapter because I want replacing fragments in viewpager.

I have already did this using listview and viewpager but only first row will come with fragments and viewpager . Other rows is not accepted the fragments . I don`t know what is the issue.

View Pager Code:

```css
 private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
 SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();
 public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
  super(fm);
  System.out.println("value with in loop=============1::");
 }

 @Override
 public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
  switch(pos) {

   case 0:
    System.out.println("value with in loop=============2:");

                FirstFragment f = new FirstFragment();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("msg", "Instance0");

                f.setArguments(b);

    return f;
   case 1:
                System.out.println("value with in loop=============2:");

                SecondFragment f2 = new SecondFragment();
                Bundle b2 = new Bundle();
                b2.putString("msg", "Instance1");

                f2.setArguments(b2);

                return f2;
   case 2: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 1");
   case 3: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 2");
   case 4: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 3");
   default: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Default");

  }
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
  return 5;
 }
}
```

ListViewCode:

```css
@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   if(convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    convertView = inflater.inflate(com.andtinder.R.layout.std_card_inner, parent, false);
    assert convertView != null;
   }
            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
            MyPagerAdapter adapter1=new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            pager.setAdapter(adapter1);

  }
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: @gabber , I have updated the code . Review it.